# ASP.net and HTML File Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

**Problem:** I'm working on a site written with a master page and a wrapper form.  The page I'm writing needs to upload a file to the server to be validated.

**What's needed:** A way to submit a file without using a form and receive that form on the server in a `WebMethod`.

**What I've tried:** Using an `XMLHttpRequest` to send `FormData` to a `WebMethod`.   The `FormData` is created and the file is appended like so:

```
let dataXML = new FormData();
dataXML.append("xml", $("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
```

sent it like this:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
        // Do stuff with the request.responseText
};
request.open("POST", PageName + "/" + Route, true);
request.send(dataXML);
```

with a `webMethod` like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string myWebMethod(MultipartFormDataContent Files)
{
    // Do stuff with the file
}
```

The `WebMethod` does not run at all.  I'm assuming this is an issue with the `WebMethod` and its parameters.  If I look at `Page_Init()` (which is run because it's returning the pages html right now rather than running my `WebMethod`) I can see the file in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0]` but I don't know how to make the `WebMethod` run.

And before anyone says it: yes, I tried JQuery AJAX but it doesn't make a difference, the problem doesn't appear to be client side (the file was uploaded in both cases).  I don't really care between JQuery AJAX and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: It could be a permissions issue. The account running the web server might not have permissions to write the file? Just a guess though.

Comment: I'm not trying to save it anywhere other than the temp location it gets saved to on upload.  I need to immediately consume the data and can discard the uploaded file after I have what I need from it.